# How to know the termination of app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to know the termination of app?

I added this code in `viewDidLoad`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification 
object : nil];
```

and if the app ends, it will notify me of termination.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification*) notif{
    NSLog(@"program will end");
}
```

But it doesn't work...
I terminated the app, by clicking home button and pressing home button in 2sec, followed by clicking app icon's '-'button.

I want to be notified of the termination of app.
And also intereseted in what function to be called when the app terminates.(is it viewDidLoad?)
And the termination of app by clicking the '-'button is to send the app SIGKILL?

Comment: I guess your app just went to the background state, that why it have not hit applicatonWillTerminate

Comment: No, surely, i terminated the app. click the home button, click the icon's '-' button following clicking the app button in 2sec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I terminated the app, by clicking home button and pressing home button in 2sec, followed by clicking app icon's '-'button.

If you press the home button, your app will be sent to the background. When you then kill it (by pressing the `-` button), it likely does not get the notification because it is not running anymore.

`applicationWillTerminate` is called on iOS < 4.0, when no multitasking (background) is available or when `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` is set in the info.plist file.

On iOS 4.x, when your app is sent to the background, it receives `applicationWillEnterForeground:`. Look at the [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground:) for more info:

> You should use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.

Keep in mind that you need to do this both in `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `applicationWillTerminate` if you also support iOS < 4

Have a look also at [this post from S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121005/iphone-sdk-3-1-3-upgrade-to-iphone-sdk-4-applicationwillterminate-and-dealloc-not).

Comment: Then, how to be notified of the apps termination?

Comment: It seems that there is no reliable way to be notified of that (that is why I posted that link to the other S.O. post about this, and there are more). May I ask why you need that?

Comment: I want to save the information that is edited during working, I wish that the saving is done when the app terminates.

Comment: You have to do that in `applicationWillEnterForeground:` as per Apple specs.

Comment: Thanks but notification that notify me termination of app is not working.

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate` will only work for iOS < 4... On what iOS version are you running your app? See my edit and the quote from Apple, as well.

Answer (score 1):

That should work, did you try adding logging into the application delegate method `applicationWillTerminate:` method too?

Edit:

For iOS 4+ devices, you need to do whatever work for shutdown in applicationWillEnterBackground instead... that always gets called as you are being suspended and is the right time to do final work.

Comment: in - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application  method

Answer (score 0):

you should implement `applicationDidEnterBackground` and do any preparation for termination there.  If your app is terminated in the background, you will receive no other notification.

Comment: Oh... Then how to save the edited information? that changed when I edit, add, delete some information.. Doesn't it need to be done when the app terminates?

Comment: If you're talking about edits that happen when the app is open, you should be doing them at their appropriate times depending on your app.  Otherwise, save any other data in didEnterBackground, pretend that is your terminate notification, because unless the app is foregrounded again before being terminated, it is.